# "ValueError: Incompatible Language version 13. Must not be between 9 and 12" with Google Colab

Tags: java, python, pytorch, data-science, google-colaboratory

I am trying to build a deep learning model with transformer model architecture. In that case when I am trying to cleaning the dataset following error occurred.

I am using Pytorch and google colab for that case & trying to clean Java methods and comment dataset.

**Tested Code**

```
    import re
    
    from fast_trees.core import FastParser
    
    parser = FastParser('java')
    
    def get_cmt_params(cmt: str) -> List[str]:
        '''
        Grabs the parameter identifier names from a JavaDoc comment
    
        :param cmt: the comment to extract the parameter identifier names from
        :returns: an array of the parameter identifier names found in the given comment
        '''
        params = re.findall('@param+\s+\w+', cmt)
        param_names = []
        for param in params:
            param_names.append(param.split()[1])
        
        return param_name
```

**Occured Error**

```
Downloading repo https://github.com/tree-sitter/tree-sitter-java to /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/fast_trees/tree-sitter-java.
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-31-64f6fa6ed39b> in <module>()
          3 from fast_trees.core import FastParser
          4 
    ----> 5 parser.set_language = FastParser('java')
          6 
          7 def get_cmt_params(cmt: str) -> List[str]:
    
    3 frames
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/fast_trees/core.py in FastParser(lang)
         96     }
         97 
    ---> 98     return PARSERS[lang]()
    
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/fast_trees/core.py in __init__(self)
         46 
         47     def __init__(self):
    ---> 48         super().__init__()
         49 
         50     def get_method_parameters(self, mthd: str) -> List[str]:
    
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/fast_trees/core.py in __init__(self)
         15 class BaseParser:
         16     def __init__(self):
    ---> 17         self.build_parser()
         18 
         19     def build_parser(self):
    
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/fast_trees/core.py in build_parser(self)
         35         self.language = Language(build_dir, self.LANG)
         36         self.parser = Parser()
    ---> 37         self.parser.set_language(self.language)
         38 
         39 # Cell
    
    ValueError: Incompatible Language version 13. Must not be between 9 and 12
```

an anybody help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

`fast_trees` uses `tree_sitter` and according to `tree_sitter` repo [it is an incomatibility issue](https://github.com/tree-sitter/py-tree-sitter/issues/38#issuecomment-703162064). If you know the owner of `fast_trees` ask them to upgrade their `tree_sitter` version.

Or you can fork it and upgrade it yourself, but keep in mind it may not be backwards compatible if you take it upon yourself and it may not be just a simple new version install.

Answer (score 2):

The `fast-trees` library uses the `tree-sitter` library and since they recommended using the `0.2.0` version of `tree-sitter` in order to use `fast-trees`. Although downgrade the `tree-sitter` to the `0.2.0` version will not be resolved your problem. I also tried out it by downgrading it.

So, without investing time to figure out the bug in `tree-sitter` it is better to move to another stable library that satisfies your requirements. So, as your requirement, you need to extract features from a given java code. So, you can use `javalang` library to extract features from a given java code.

> `javalang` is a pure Python library for working with Java source code.
> `javalang` provides a lexer and parser targeting Java 8. The
> implementation is based on the Java language spec available at
> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/.

you can refer it from - https://pypi.org/project/javalang/0.13.0/

Since `javalang` is a pure library it will help go forward on your research without any bugs